# Using JSTL's formatDate function with a date represented in milliseconds

Tags: jsp, jstl, jsp-tags, jspx, formatdatetime

Normally I use the following to display a Date object in a JSP page:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${blogEntry.created}"/>
```

Works great if `blogEntry.created` is a `java.util.Date` object.  But what's the proper way to display a date if you only have a date in milliseconds?  Do I have to first set a variable with escaped Java code like `<%=new java.util.Date(millis);%>`?  Or is there a better way?

Comment: Can you just add a method to the `BlogEntry` class that returns the date as a proper `Date`? `<fmt:formatDate value="${blogEntry.createdAsDate}"/>`

Comment: @Matt -- if you post that as an answer, I'll vote it up.

Comment: @Jacob: that does not answer the concrete question, the OP is perfectly aware of that.

Comment: @BalusC - you're correct, I was looking for the best way to deal with dates provided to the JSP page in millis and thought there had to be a better way than ugly <%='s. I'm not always in control of the object with the time, so not ideal but I credited the above as the answer I was able to make it work somewhat elegantly with a kind of wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just add a method to the `BlogEntry` class that returns the date as a proper `java.util.Date`?

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${blogEntry.createdAsDate}"/>
```

Comment: I'm not completely in control of this, but I can make it work this way.